# Why isn't this webkit keyframe valid .less?

Tags: animation, css, less

I have a little keyframe animation I use occastionally, it looks like so:

```
@-webkit-keyframes zoom-zoom {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(.1);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    70% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Works fine in a .CSS file but I'm converting this site to use less.js so all my stylesheet are getting rewritten, but this won't process. It throws an error when it gets to 0% saying it's not valid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using [less.php](http://leafo.net/lessphp) to compile .less to .css and it handles CSS3 animations properly. You can use the [less.php demo](http://leafo.net/lessphp/#demo) to see it for yourself.

I guess this is a bug in the less.js compiler, you may want to consider reporting in on the github [bug tracker](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues) of less.js. Till you get an official answer there, you can just use less.php for compiling it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that less was written before people started using these animations, so doesn't nknow what they are.

I use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) (same thing but better :) ), which parses them fine. Alternatively, maybe less has a newer version where they parse them.